# Find and get specific rows in javascript or php

Tags: javascript

Search for ''Customer_011111''.
If found then get second class inner html + third class inner html.
Print: 110

```html
<td class="small">Text1</td>
<td class="small">Customer_011111</td>
<td class="small">10</td>
<td class="small">100</td>
<td class="small">1000</td>
<td class="small">10000</td>
```

Comment: Great! But you haven't shown us what you have tried. Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service or a *"how to"* tutorial service. The objective is to help you with **your code**. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: show us your javascript code

Comment: Sorry i have googled a lot but cant find anything. Im totaly stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a javascript version

```js
var match = 'Customer_011111',
    firstSibling = null,
    secondSibling = null;

window.onload = function(){
  var selector = document.querySelectorAll('td');
  for (i = 0; i < selector.length; ++i){
    if(selector[i].innerHTML == match){
      firstSibling = Number(selector[i+1].innerHTML);
      secondSibling = Number(selector[i+2].innerHTML);
      var answer = document.createElement('div');
      answer.innerHTML = firstSibling + secondSibling;
      document.body.appendChild(answer);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="small">Text1</td>
    <td class="small">Customer_011111</td>
    <td class="small">10</td>
    <td class="small">100</td>
    <td class="small">1000</td>
    <td class="small">10000</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Have tested this but it doesnt work. Nothing gets printed out :(

Comment: @FastXX if you hit run code snippet you should see 10 and 100 printed in the console log. If you are running your own test with your html, make sure you have the td element wrapped in a table and tr element otherwise it might not work. I've upated the example to add the numbers.

Comment: Well i can see it only when i click Run code snippet. When i try to use it on my own page it doesnt do anything. I have everything in same file and the script inside a <script></script> tag.

Would need it to be printed out ;)

Comment: Are your td elements wrapped in a tr with a parent table

Comment: Yes i think so its a big table but this is how its looks https://pastebin.com/Zn0VdYsh

Your code works but it only prints to console how to print it on the web?

Comment: document.write(firstSibling.innerHTML+secondSibling.innerHTML);

Comment: But now it prints 10100 it doesnt add these numbers. The result should be 110 not 10100.

Comment: @FastXX it should be good now I just needed to typecast the text to a number. sorry

Comment: @FastXX run the example above and you will see 110. You need to make sure you typecast the innerHTML with Number() otherwise it just joins two strings i.e 10100

Comment: I have saved this code that you have posted erlier this code works better https://pastebin.com/2JJbQbhd but like but like i sed 10100 instead of 110. So what is typecast?

Comment: @FastXX When you hit run code snippet above do you see 110 on the second line? When you get a value from a text node it returns a string. If you add two strings in javascript they will concatenate e.g. 'a'+'b' == 'ab'   '1'+'2' =='12'. So you are converting the strings to numbers like Number('1')

Comment: Yes but why isnt it working when i try that script on my own? Btw this latest updted you made those not work at all.

Comment: @FastXX did you manage to get it running or are you still having issues?

Comment: Ne not this latest script. This old script which you posted worked but it doesnt add up numbers. Prints out 10100. This script: https://pastebin.com/fVjKmjcy

Comment: document.write(Number(firstSibling.innerHTML)+Number(secondSibling.innerHTML)); That's because you're not converting the string to a number. Change the last line to the above

Comment: Are you getting error? Maybe set up a jsbin and post the link and then we can see what your trying!

Comment: <script>your javascript</script> <table>...</table> (All in the same file)

Comment: @FastXX If you set something like in the link below and paste a link here it'll help us debug the code. As you've said the example above works as required, so it must be something else. https://jsbin.com/katulaqewe/edit?output

Answer (score 0):

If you have jquery in your project then you can do something like:

```
$('.small').each(function(){
 if ($(this).html() == 'Customer_011111'){
     //this is the found element
     var second = $(this).next().next();
     var third = second.next();
     var secondHtml = second.html();
     var thirdHtml = third.html();
}
})
```

Comment: How do i try this out i have inserted this code between <script> </script> tag but it doesnt want to work?